# Error installing rvm (Ruby version Manager)

Tags: rvm

I was trying to install Ruby Version Manager for installing Ruby on Rails.

I am following this link. : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

However, I am getting this error.

```
$ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0      8      0  0:00:23  0:00:20  0:00:03   562
100 11861  100 11861    0     0    251      0  0:00:47  0:00:47 --:--:--  1974
Warning, --auto is deprecated in favor of --auto-dotfiles.
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124  100   124    0     0      5      0  0:00:24  0:00:23  0:00:01    35
100 1631k  100 1631k    0     0   5867      0  0:04:44  0:04:44 --:--:-- 11223

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status ''.
```

Comment: You need to try again, I just pushed a fix that will show error code from curl, then you can check with `man curl | grep '<the-errror-number>'`

Comment: Surprisingly, there is no error now.

Comment: I bet for a temporary network error.

Comment: Yes, could be. I had tried 4-5 times during that half hour duration. Thankfully, it works now.

Comment: Behind a proxy, maybe you forgot to configure your https_proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you cannot download the package from github. By my side, no problem to download the package at `https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz` with a browser. If you get same error in a browser, you've probably a network problem.

Answer (score 2):

1) Install RVM

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
(Refer  https://rvm.io/rvm/install/)
$ source /home/sodel/.rvm/scripts/rvm ( enable rvm)
```

This installs latest stable ruby.
To install another version run rvm install

2) `rvm install 1.9.3` (it will install ruby 1.9.3)

3) `rvm use 1.9.3` (to use latest version of ruby)

4) Start installing gems Ex: `gem install bundle`

5) `bundle install` (for all gems)

Comment: after wasting 3 hours on this error, I have found this solution to be the right one on the internet.

PS: my system ryzn 5, win10, ran these coomands on Ubuntu for windows.

Hopw that help you guys

Answer (score 2):

***Install RVM with RUBY***

> **sudo apt-get install curl**

after install
install rvm also ruby

> **\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable**

if you face issue with the above line (Failed to connect to get.rvm.io port 443: Network is unreachable)

in browser go to **https://get.rvm.io** save the page in any location

> **make it executable** file name rvm-installer
>
> **chmod +x rvm-installer**
>
> then do the following
>
> **bash rvm-installer stable --ruby**

then check **rvm list**
note the version of ruby listing on terminal

**change terminal to login shell. open a new terminal **

then **rvm use 2.1.1**   => ( 2.1.1 version )

then its done!

pd@admin:~$ **ruby -v**

ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]

---

```
STEPS
1: go to [https://get.rvm.io][1] save the page in in home directory(filename rvm-installer) 
2: chmod +x rvm-installer
3: bash rvm-installer stable --ruby
4:rvm use 2.1.1
5:gem install rails
```

programmers keep on coding with ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your antivirus if you have any, I had same problem with Avast when getting rails from rubygems.org, it was blocking http connection for some reason. Try disable your antivirus if you have any and retry.

Answer (score 1):

On my cygwin system was no curl installed. Instead there must a version on my windows that was used by the cygwin subsystem.

I've installed curl via the cygwin setup.exe and all things run file.

Answer (score 1):

From what i had seen , there was an error prior to this error . It stated curl was outdated . I had to upgrade curl and den again i continued with installing rvm . Worked for me , though the network error also has a high possibility of occurring .

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu use its package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the similar error i resolved it by changing `https` to `http` for more clarification you can look at the below screen short.

[image: Installing RVM using Cygwin]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem but i removed "secure part from the url and it works for me"
try this one

```
$ curl -L http://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

This is an internet protocol problem. I did it before curl and everything works fine

```
echo ipv4 >> ~/.curlrc
```

So my steps are:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
echo ipv4 >> ~/.curlrc
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```