# Curl returns Error status 22 when installing rvm from get.rvm.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I was trying to install Ruby on Rails using RVM. As the first step, I had to download rvm and used  the following code.

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

It seems like curl have successfully downloaded the file from get.rvm.io and called bash to run it.
The downloaded script is attempting to download rvm installation file but fails with following error.

```
Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz'.
curl returned status '22'.
```

All the answers given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730689/cant-install-rvm-on-linux-mint-14 and
[Error installing rvm (Ruby version Manager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701058/error-installing-rvm-ruby-version-manager)

are tried but failed to resolve the problem.

Is there any method to resolve this problem or an alternate way to install latest version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails (with or without using rvm).

I was able to reproduce the error on two different PCs on two different networks with Linux Mint 12 and Linux mint 14.

Here is the command-line output shown:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    142      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   508
100 13784  100 13784    0     0   4588      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 24353
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124  100   124    0     0     88      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   128
  0   124    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 502

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '22'.
```

Comment: hi vishnuprasad.. i didn't find any of your contact info,that is why i am writing here. I found you working on a project in elance(yesterday) about paypal integration. I am also a freelancer like you. Could you please give me your contact info??? May be in future we can both work on big projects. my elance https://www.elance.com/s/suhailvs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s head
```

there are no big changes on master compared to stable and everything should be just fine

Comment: the stable url was accidentally locked when github.com was under DoS attack, it's unlocked already.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub experinced a DoS attack today (https://status.github.com/messages):

> GitHub.com is undergoing a series of DoS attacks. We're temporarily
>   degrading several of our services as we continue to fight off these
>   attacks.

Probably you need to try once more.